# remove array object by id

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, array-splice

I'm trying to remove array object in ionic storage by id. But it not working as expected..What should I do. This is my code

**page.ts**

```
 removeItem(id){
    this.storage.get('storedAdd').then((val) => {
      console.log(Object.keys(val))
      Object.keys(val).splice(id, 1)
      console.log(val)
     for(let element of Object.keys(val)){
        console.log(val[element])
        val[element].id.toString().splice(id,1)
         this.storage.set('storeAdd', val)
          console.log(val)
     }
}
```

I using splice but got this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: val[element].id.toString(...).splice is not a function
TypeError: val[element].id.toString(...).splice is not a function
```

> Edit
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cant use toString at there because **The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.**
Example to remove key is 0: I have use delete

```
let myObject = {
  0: {
        "id" : 1,
        "text": "text1"
    },
 1: {
        "id" : 2,
        "text": "text2"
    }
};

delete myObject[0];
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..Sure...I've edit my question

Comment: If you want remove key 0 from object. I think you can try **delete val[0]**

Comment: Yes. This is my example. You can try at console in browser :)) 

`let myObject = {
  0: {
  "id" : 1,
  "text": "text1"
 },
 1: {
  "id" : 2,
  "text": "text2"
 }
};
//remove key 0
delete myObject[0];
console.log(myObject);`

Comment: Can i see your code ?
Can i know what do you want delete at your objects? 
Maybe. i can help you.

Comment: `for(let element of Object.keys(val)){
        console.log(val[element])
        delete val[element].id
        if (id != val[element].id) {
          this.storage.set('storeAdd', val)
          console.log(val)
        }
     }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224135/discussion-between-mai-truong-and-javiens).